# Viewmodel is always null

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

```
         **This is My ViewModel**
        namespace TipCalc.Core
         { 
           public class ProductModel : MvxViewModel
        {
            public string productname{ get; set;}
            public string productprice{ get; set;}
            public ProductModel()
        {
            productname="qwe";
            productprice="123";
      }
        //This is my view model
   }
 }



   **This is my View**

       public class ViewOfProduct : MvxFragment
{

    public new ProductModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (ProductModel) base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }



    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ViewOfProduct, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I am working with xamrin android application and I am using MvvmCross.I get ProductModel(ViewModel) always null in view.So i can't bind data to the control.Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BindingInflate to use data binding inside the view:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = this.BindingInflate(FragmentId, null);
        return view;
    }
```

Also i would recommend using gerenics to set the viewmodel:

```
public class SomeFragment : MvxFragment<SomeViewModel>
```

A full sample app is available here:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/master/Samples/Example.Droid/Activities/MainActivity.cs#L33